# WordPress: Empty row is added on page (load / refresh)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm struggling with data insertion in the database. I have created a form and the values are stored in a table. When i reload or refresh the page an empty row or the last stored values are stored in the db. I don't know how to resolve it. I really need your help. 
This is my code

```
<?php get_header();?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Form validation code will come here.
function validate()  
{ 
if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )
{
alert( "Please provide your name!" );
document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
return false;
}

if(document.myForm.percentage.value =="")
{
alert("please fill the percentage value");
document.myForm.percentage.focus();
return false; 
}
if( document.myForm.EMail.value == "" )
{
alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
return false;
}
if( document.myForm.Phone.value == "" ||
isNaN( document.myForm.Phone.value ) ||
document.myForm.Phone.value.length != 10 )
{
alert( "Please provide a valid phone number" );
document.myForm.Phone.focus() ;
return false;
}
if( document.myForm.Country.value == "-1" )
{
alert( "Please provide your country!" );
return false;
}
return true;
}
//-->
</script>






<form  name="myForm"  method="post"   onsubmit="return(validate());">
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2" >name<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="Name" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2" >email<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="EMail" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2" >Phone<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="Phone" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2" >Date of birth</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="text" name="dateofbirth" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2" >College</div>
<div class="col-md-4">


</div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2">Year of Passed out</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="yearofpassedout" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2">Percentage<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="percentage" /></div>
</div><!--row ends-->
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2">Skills</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="skills" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2">Certification</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="certification"/></div>
</div><!--row ends-->
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2"> Country<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select name="Country">
<option value="-1" selected>[choose yours]</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">UK</option>
<option value="3">INDIA</option>
</select>
</div>
</div><!--row ends-->


<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="background:orange;padding:10px 40px;text-align:center;"/><input type="button" value="Cancel" style="background:orange;padding:10px 40px;text-align:center;margin-left:5px;"/></div>
</div>

</form>



<?php
$wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{


$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$EMail = $_POST["EMail"];
$Phone = $_POST["Phone"];
$dateofbirth=$_POST["dateofbirth"];
$college = $_POST["college"];
$department = $_POST["department"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$certification=$_POST["certification"];
$skills=$_POST["skills"];
$percentage=$_POST["percentage"];
$yearofpassedout=$_POST["yearofpassedout"];

if($wpdb->insert('student_profile',array("Name"=> $Name,"EMail"=>$EMail,"Phone"=>$Phone,"dateofbirth"=>$dateofbirth,"college"=>$college,"department"=>$department,"yearofpassedout"=>$yearofpassedout,"percentage"=>$percentage,"skills"=>$skills,"certification"=>$certification,"country"=>$country),array("%s","%s","%d","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")))
{
echo "insert succesfully";


}
else{ 
echo "there is error in insert query.";
}
}

?>




</div><!--TAB CONTENT ENDS HERE-->



<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this, you must use [`isset()`](http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/isset.php), The `isset ()` function is used to check whether a variable is set or not.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$EMail = $_POST["EMail"];
$Phone = $_POST["Phone"];
$dateofbirth=$_POST["dateofbirth"];
$college = $_POST["college"];
$department = $_POST["department"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$certification=$_POST["certification"];
$skills=$_POST["skills"];
$percentage=$_POST["percentage"];
$yearofpassedout=$_POST["yearofpassedout"];

$wpdb->insert('student_profile',array("Name"=>      $Name,"EMail"=>$EMail,"Phone"=>$Phone,"dateofbirth"=>$dateofbirth,"college"=>$college,"depar   tment"=>$department,"yearofpassedout"=>$yearofpassedout,"percentage"=>$percentage,"skills"=>$skills,"certification"=>$certification,"country"=>$country),array("%s","%s","%d","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s"));
}
?>
```

now your code only execute when the submit button will hit..

Thanks...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dk-Macadamia, but still i have the same problem. Last value which i submitted is getting added in to the database as i reload my page.

Comment: i cant able to send ma full code through the comment option

Comment: <?php
global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$EMail = $_POST["EMail"];
$Phone = $_POST["Phone"];$dateofbirth=$_POST["dateofbirth"];
$college = $_POST["college"];
$department = $_POST["department"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$certification=$_POST["certification"];
$skills=$_POST["skills"];
$percentage=$_POST["percentage"];$yearofpassedout=$_POST["yearofpassedout"];

Comment: i have uploaded my code please check it and tell me. Thank you

Comment: thanks a lot mr.DK-Macadamia, its working well thank you so much.

Comment: hi Mr.Dk-Macadamia again i got the same problem. Today when i run the same application the details are storing again and again as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php get_header();?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Form validation code will come here.
function validate() 
{ 
if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )
{
alert( "Please provide your name!" );
document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
return false;
}

if(document.myForm.percentage.value =="")
{
alert("please fill the percentage value");
document.myForm.percentage.focus();
return false; 
}
if( document.myForm.EMail.value == "" )
{
alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
return false;
}
if( document.myForm.Phone.value == "" ||
isNaN( document.myForm.Phone.value ) ||
document.myForm.Phone.value.length != 10 )
{
alert( "Please provide a valid phone number" );
document.myForm.Phone.focus() ;
return false;
}
if( document.myForm.Country.value == "-1" )
{
alert( "Please provide your country!" );
return false;
}
return true;
}
//-->
</script>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
  global $wpdb;
$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$EMail = $_POST["EMail"];
$Phone = $_POST["Phone"];
$dateofbirth=$_POST["dateofbirth"];
$college = $_POST["college"];
$department = $_POST["department"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$certification=$_POST["certification"];
$skills=$_POST["skills"];
$percentage=$_POST["percentage"];
$yearofpassedout=$_POST["yearofpassedout"];

if($wpdb->insert('student_profile',array("Name"=> $Name,"EMail"=>$EMail,"Phone"=>$Phone,"dateofbirth"=>$dateofbirth,"college"=>$college,"department"=>$department,"yearofpassedout"=>$yearofpassedout,"percentage"=>$percentage,"skills"=>$skills,"certification"=>$certification,"country"=>$country),array("%s","%s","%d","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")))
{
    echo "insert succesfully";
}
else{ 
echo "there is error in insert query.";
}
}
?>






<form  name="myForm"  method="post"   onsubmit="return(validate());">
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2" >name<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="Name" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2" >email<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="EMail" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2" >Phone<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="Phone" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2" >Date of birth</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="text" name="dateofbirth" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2" >College</div>
<div class="col-md-4">


</div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2">Year of Passed out</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="yearofpassedout" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2">Percentage<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="percentage" /></div>
</div><!--row ends-->
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2">Skills</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="skills" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2">Certification</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="certification"/></div>
</div><!--row ends-->
<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-2"> Country<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;">*</span></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select name="Country">
<option value="-1" selected>[choose yours]</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">UK</option>
<option value="3">INDIA</option>
</select>
</div>
</div><!--row ends-->


<div class="row" id="enquirynew">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="background:orange;padding:10px 40px;text-align:center;"/><input type="button" value="Cancel" style="background:orange;padding:10px 40px;text-align:center;margin-left:5px;"/></div>
</div>

</form>


</div><!--TAB CONTENT ENDS HERE-->



<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your quick reply Mr.Shashank, its working.

Comment: hi mr.shashank again i got the same problem, even i tried your code but still the same problem is repeating. can you help me to resolve it?

Comment: again im getting the same problem shashank

Comment: Now what error are you getting..? I mean to ask that now all script ruuning well without any error but still blank value is inserting in db or any other error is produced.like syntax error or any?

Comment: i didnt get any error, when i reload the page or refresh it the data which i saved last is storing again in to the database i.e the last data is storing again in to the db.

Comment: I have checked you code. It is working fine for me. But why not in your case!!  have you put insert query on your page elsewhere outside the if condition besides the previous one?

Comment: Nope i have searched my full theme but i didnt use it anywhere except this page. I dont know what to do.

Comment: I did some modification in your current code. replace your code with my new code and then try and then Let me know what you get. but backup your current code before doing it @user3539727.

Comment: i tried it by using your code but again the same issue. Im getting the alert insert successfully.But when i reload my page it showing that insert successfully and the values are again stored in db.

Comment: Hey..one seconds, just try to put if($_POST['submit']=='Submit') in place of if(isset($_POST['submit'])) and pls let me know.

Comment: It means your if condition is not setting false in any condition. then what if we set this condition as if(false) in plase of if(isset($_POST['submit'])).

Comment: again blank/previous data is inserting even after setting if condition to false..??

Comment: no im not getting the blank data, the data which i submitted last is storing again in to the database.

Comment: can you please update your code with your current code.?

Comment: Replace $wpbd with global $wpdb and put it in if condition as same as in my updated answer.

Comment: i did it but same issue shashank.its storing the same value again and again as the page reloads.

Comment: no way here..just remove your insert db query and reload page then what happens.? still you are getting same issue.?

Comment: i did it, the value is not storing in to the database again. only one time it stored in the db.